# Single SQL Query to Get Task Status

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I would appreciate any help the community can offer helping me write a SQL query to achieve the following, or, if it is not possible, offer a method to do so.

Objective: Return a result like below:

```
subtaskID | subtaskQueueID | subtaskName | timeComplete        | jobID | approver 
--------- | -------------- | ----------- | ------------------- | ------| --------
23        | 2              | Review #1   | 2017-08-14 00:00:00 | 840   | Bill
24        | 2              | Review #2   | 2017-08-14 01:00:00 | 840   | John
25        | 2              | Review #3   | NULL                | 840   | NULL
26        | 2              | Review #4   | NULL                | 840   | NULL
```

The source tables:

**Job_subtasks_status**

```
jobID | subtaskID    | timeComplete        | approver
----- | ------------ | ------------------- | --------
840   | 23           | 2017-08-14 00:00:00 | Bill
840   | 24           | 2017-08-14 01:00:00 | John
```

**Job_subtasks**

```
subtaskID | subtaskQueueID | subtaskName
--------- | -------------- | -----------
23        | 2              | Review #1
24        | 2              | Review #2
25        | 2              | Review #3
26        | 2              | Review #4
27        | 4              | Funding Approval
28        | 4              | Requirement Approval
```

The important bit to note is I want to return all records from Job_subtasks that when subtaskQueueID=2, and NULLs if there is no record in Job_subtasks_status (a NULL indicates the subtask was not completed).

I thought a standard LEFT JOIN would do, so I tried the following query:

```
SELECT A.subtaskID, A.subtaskQueueID, A.subtaskName, B.timeComplete, B.jobID, B.approver 
FROM Job_subtasks A LEFT JOIN Job_subtasks_status B ON A.subtaskID=B.subtaskID 
WHERE B.subtaskID=2 AND B.jobID=840
```

Comment: Your conditions on the right table turns the `LEFT JOIN` into 'INNER JOIN'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using the `LEFT OUTER JOIN`. This will return all the values from the from "Job_subtasks" table that `subtaskQueueID=2`

```
Select     A.subtaskID, 
           A.subtaskQueueID, 
           A.subtaskName, 
           B.timeComplete, 
           B.jobID, 
           B.approver 
From       Job_subtasks        A 
Left Outer Join Job_subtasks_status B  On  A.subtaskID = B.subtaskID 
                                  And B.subtaskID = 2 
                                  And B.jobID = 840
```

the Result should be:

```
subtaskID | subtaskQueueID | subtaskName | timeComplete        | jobID | approver 
--------- | -------------- | ----------- | ------------------- | ------| --------
23        | 2              | Review #1   | 2017-08-14 00:00:00 | 840   | Bill
24        | 2              | Review #2   | 2017-08-14 01:00:00 | 840   | John
25        | 2              | Review #3   | NULL                | 840   | NULL
26        | 2              | Review #4   | NULL                | 840   | NULL
```

Comment: Thank you!  I didn't know you could do that.

Answer (score 0):

Your `WHERE` clause is filtering out the `NULL` results from the `LEFT JOIN` (`WHERE` executes *after* the `OUTER JOIN`).

Add those conditions to the `ON` clause:

```
Select     A.subtaskID, 
           A.subtaskQueueID, 
           A.subtaskName, 
           B.timeComplete, 
           B.jobID, 
           B.approver 
From       Job_subtasks        A 
Left Join  Job_subtasks_status B  On  A.subtaskID = B.subtaskID 
                                  And B.subtaskID = 2 
                                  And B.jobID = 840
```

Answer (score 0):

Conditions on the *second* table in a `left join` should go in the `on` clause:

```
SELECT js.subtaskID, js.subtaskQueueID, js.subtaskName,
       jss.timeComplete, jss.jobID, jss.approver 
FROM Job_subtasks js LEFT JOIN
     Job_subtasks_status jss
     ON js.subtaskID = jss.subtaskID AND jss.subtaskID = 2 AND jss.jobID = 840;
```

I also strongly recommend that you use meaningful table aliases.

Why does the condition go there?  A `left join` keeps all rows in the first table plus matching rows in the second.  If there is no match, the columns from the second table are `NULL` -- and the `WHERE` clause filters them out.